# LEft operand error

Tags: iphone

```
   I need to change only xoffset of my textfield on a particular event . I am writing the following line .
```

*fileNametext.frame.origin.x = 300.0;*

But I am getting the following error .

*error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment*

Can somebody please help me ? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
fileNametext.frame = CGFrameMake(300, fileNametext.frame.origin.y, fileNametext.frame.size.width, fileNametext.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that error, I'd say that 'x' is either an accessor method or a read-only property.  Try what Josh said.